# Excel Addin does not compile properly on different machines

Tags: c#, excel, tfs, add-in

I have a very old Visual Studio Excel AddIn project.

When I compile it on my machine on VS2013 (.Net 4.0) and Office 2010 it works perfectly on the other machines. But when I compile it on TFS machine (no Office, only the vsto_redist.exe) it does not work - it does not load.

I've tried to switch on the VSTO_LOGALERTS and VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS but this did not show any errors.

I've also tried to add a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to the project it still does not worked.

Any help on how I can see the problem will be helpful.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile o on your TFS server? TFS sites your asset and that Sean's a little risky!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install at lest the Excel developer tools that cinder in the box with office.